# how to define Undefined variable: token (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\auth\passwords\email.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-authentication

[image]

> Undefined variable: token (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\auth\passwords\email.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used default auth(using `php artisan make:auth`) in laravel then change like this in *`\auth\passwords\email.blade.php`* file:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.email') }}">
@csrf
```

Answer (score 0):

In the form you don't need to add `$token`, you are already using it in the form. So your form action should be

```
action="{{ route('password.request') }}"
```

Also for `csrf` you can make input in the form by using following

`{{ csrf_field() }}`

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had same issue with my #laravel6 project where i was trying to call same method and view from different URL.
I simply removed the second line after @csrf  like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">
```

I removed this and its works fine.
and about token there is a token from @csrf so everything works as it is.

Answer (score -1):

You just don't need to add `$token` manually in the form, you can just use `csrf_field()` inside the form and it'll generate the hidden field with csrf token

Your code should be like this

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

Comment: Check image in his question line 18 $token not found there not in CSRF field